# where are the screen resolution settings on KDE

Tags: resolution, settings

Where are the screen resolution settings? I started the KDE system settings and see this:

[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]

Are there somewhere else? Where?

Or is something broken? Maybe some missing permissions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, something is wrong. This window is supposed to host at least two tabs, and resolution settings are on another tab.
This will show you what KCM modules are present.

```
kcmshell4 hardware --list
```

The one called `kcm_kscreen` must be present. May be you should reinstall kscreen package

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kscreen
```

Comment: Maybe a restart of the display manager or a reboot works already.

Comment: May be. It was written 3 years ago, and, I think I had KDE4 in mind. Control Panel had been reworked since then. Anyway, I ditched KDE in favor of Cinnamon.